# Javascript if/else statement isnt working however the code inside does as i have tested without the if/else

Tags: javascript, html, css, if-statement, width

Basically i have tried to create an if else statement that checks the width of a div and then depending on the result will expand or contract the iframe that i have inside. Their are no problems in running the code itself just the if/else statement as i have tested the code inside without the if/else

site can be found at http://l3mmydubz.onhub.online

Code:

Javascript:

```
var sc = document.getElementById("scfullscreen");
var sccount = 0;
$(document).ready(function() {
$(sc).click(function() {
sccount= sccount+1;
if (sccount%2 === 0) {
    animateFn('20%','80%');
    $('#soundcloud').animate({
            left: '20%',
            width: '80%',
        }, 1000);

} else {
    animateFN('0%','20%');
    }
});
});

function animateFn(l, w){
    $('#soundcloud').animate({
            left: l,
            width: w,
        }, 1000);
    $('#scfullscreen').animate({
            left: l,
            width: w,
        }, 1000);
    $('#scexpand').addClass('rotated');
}
```

html:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>

<head>
    <title>L3mmy Dubz</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="styles.css">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <script src="jquery.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="animation.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
</head>

<body>
    <div id="header"></div>
    <a href="index.html">
        <div id="homebtn" class="btn">Home</div>
    </a>
    <div id="musicbtn" class="btn">Music</div>
    <iframe id="soundcloud" scrolling="no" frameborder="no" src="https://w.soundcloud.com/player/?url=https%3A//api.soundcloud.com/users/19690125&amp;auto_play=false&amp;hide_related=false&amp;show_comments=true&amp;show_user=true&amp;show_reposts=false&amp;visual=true"></iframe>
    <div class="btn" id="scfullscreen">
        <img id="scexpand" height="100%" alt="fullscreen" src="images\plus.png" />
    </div>

</body>

</html>
```

CSS:

```
* {
margin:0px;
border:0px;
padding:0px;
}
body {
background-color:#B22800;
height:100%;
width:100%;
}
#header {
position:fixed;
left:0px;
width:20%;
height:100%;
background-color: #7C1C00;
opacity:0.9;

}
.btn {
position:fixed;
line-height:200%;
text-overflow:clip;
display: block;
overflow: hidden;
white-space: nowrap;
height:7.5%;
width:20%;
color:white;
Font-size:2em;
text-align:center;
}
.btn:hover {
background-color:#ff3a00;
}
#homebtn{
top:0%;
}
#musicbtn{
top:7.5%;
}
#header a {
text-decoration:none;
color:#fff;
}

#soundcloud {
width:20%;
height:77.5%;
position:fixed;
left:0px;
top:15%;
}
#scfullscreen {
bottom:0px;
display:block;
position:fixed;
overflow: hidden;
white-space: nowrap;
height:7.5%;
left:0px;
width:20%;
}
#scfullscreen:hover {
background-color:#ff3a00;
}
.rotated {
transform: rotate(45deg);
-ms-transform: rotate(45deg); /* IE 9 */
-moz-transform: rotate(45deg); /* Firefox */
-webkit-transform: rotate(45deg); /* Safari and Chrome */
-o-transform: rotate(45deg); /* Opera */
}
@media screen and (max-width:768px) {
#header {
    width:30%;
}
#soundcloud {
    width:30%;
}
#scfullscreen {
    width:30%;
    left:0px;
}
}
```

Comment: Please provide enough code including basic html/css to reproduce this problem

Comment: The value of `styel.left` is not a number but a string, like `"100px"` for which you can not use < or > conditions. You should cast it to integer first: `if(parseInt(sc.style.left,10) > 0)`

Comment: Thank you for your help it is appreciated

Comment: And sorry about that charliefl i have updated my question

Answer (score 0):

consider drying out your code as well.

```
var sc = document.getElementById("scfullscreen");
$(document).ready(function() {
$('#scfullscreen').click(function() {
    var l= parseInt(sc.style.left,10);
    if (l > 0) {
        animateFN('0%','20%');

    } else {
        animateFn('20%','80%');
        });
    }
});
});
});

 function animateFn(l, w){
        $('#soundcloud').animate({
                left: l,
                width: w,
            }, 1000);
        $('#scfullscreen').animate({
                left: l,
                width: w,
            }, 1000);
        $('#scexpand').addClass('rotated');
}
```

Comment: Thank you will try it now :)

Comment: for some reason it still won't work sorry for the inconvenience i have changed it so it checks the width instead here is the site i have made it live so it can be inspected l3mmydubz.onhub.online

Comment: try just var l= parseInt(sc.style.left);
    if (l > 0) {